# How to create custom email notification using php in Wordpress theme relevent post published

Tags: php, wordpress, email, plugins, phpmailer

I have a WordPress theme its a blogging theme but this theme doesn't have an inbuilt function to notify subscribers (users) via email when a new post is published by a team member on the website  There is one more thing is it possible to notify subscribers via email when the relevant post published to on the website.

Mean User "A" like to read about "Technology" so he just receives an email once the technology blog is posted not for any other blog.

Can you please help me I don't have experience with PHP
So please help

```
    if ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'edit-question') !== false ) {
        // your action or send mail goes here if the post is edited 
    } else {
            // send mail if the post is just published
            $headers = 'From: "Your Site <mail@example.com>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: mail@example.com' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
            $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            
            $to = 'my.mail@example.com';
            $subject = 'New Post Published';
            $post_title = $post->post_title;
            $message = 'Hi, new post is published on your website: ' . $post_title;
            
            wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            
        }
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'mydomain_send_mail_on_new_post', 10, 3 );

but its not working
```

Comment: WordPress includes PHPMailer, and you can customise its configuration (which changes how the `wp_mail` function behaves) through a hook script. Have a read of [this doc](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-PHPMailer-in-WordPress), and follow links from it.

Comment: You may be better off just using something like publishpress : https://wordpress.org/plugins/publishpress/

Answer (score 0):

```html
/* Please try below code for mail send if new post published */

function notifyauthor($post_id) {
$post = get_post($post_id);
$author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
$subject = "Post Published: ".$post->post_title."";
 
$message = "
      Hi ".$author->display_name.",
       
      Your post, \"".$post->post_title."\" has just been published.
       
      View post: ".get_permalink( $post_id )."
       
      Thanks"
      ;
       
   wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message);
}
add_action('publish_post', 'notifyauthor');
```